# How to customize blogger first post

Tags: html, css, blogger

Hello I want to give a different CSS style only for first post of my blog http://tutxtblogspot.com 
Here I've used `<b:if cond='data:numPosts != 0'>` 
Also I've used `<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>` 
But I've failed to apply any style for the first post my blog. 
Please help

Comment: Have a look at dom selectors and do it all with CSS. You can select the first div child of a parent, in your case the first blog on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure CSS to target different children within a parent/child block of HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Blog one</div>
    <div>Blog two</div>
    <div>Blog three</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

The CSS will only be applied to the first child.

Comment: Thanks it's working. I've changed it to .date-outer:first-child{background-image:url(&#39;http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ceopyA5SRJ4/UwD2R4B0XTI/AAAAAAAAE88/8fq6Y4C8pII/s1600/NEW.png&#39;);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 80px 80px;
background-position: left top;
}